# PowerShell to Open Outlook, Make Visible

Tags: powershell, outlook

My mission is to graduate from using PowerShell to create an instance of Outlook to simply viewing, or making visible the process that I can see in the TaskManager.

To Digress, this works for Word.Application
but not for Outlook.Application.

```
$MsApp = New-Object -comObject Word.Application 

$MsApp.Visible = $true
```

I have checked the methods but cannot find a suitable verb to open, run or make visible.

I would be so grateful for a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To activate a running Outlook that's just minimized:

```
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application").ActiveWindow().Activate()
```

To create an Outlook instance that's visible (it's simplest to just `start outlook.exe`):

```
(new-object -com Outlook.Application).GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder("olFolderInbox").GetExplorer().Display()
```

To make the code clearer:

```
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$folder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder("olFolderInbox")
$explorer = $folder.GetExplorer()
$explorer.Display()
```

Comment: It works when using `6` instead of `"olFolderInbox"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make visible an already running instance of Word or Outlook, you don't want to use New-Object.  You want to get the running object.  You can do this with a .NET call:

```
$word = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Word.Application")
$word.Visible = $true
```

Comment: @GuyThomas: Try `$outlook = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application")
$outlook.ActiveWindow().Activate()`